# slice status for the Pipeline with multiple output datasets

Tags: azure-data-factory

Lets say I have an ADF pipeline with just one activity of type Hive. And then I have say 10 output datasets for that activity. So when the pipeline is running a slice, will the slice status for all the 10 output datasets look the same in ADF monitor? Does it matter which output dataset's slice status I check in the ADF monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct. All the 10 output datasets will have the same status and you can check the status of any output dataset.